# Q. What is the difference between div and class?

Tags: html, css

It's been confusing for a **week** and I'd already search through google but still it didn't clear my mind what's the difference between these two, any clear answer?

Comment: Umm one is an HTML tag and the other is an attribute? `<class>` does not exist. `<div class="btn"></div>`

Comment: AFAIK, <class> is not a tag, its an attribute. Should I explain about `<div class='my class' > ... </div>`?

Comment: Where did you find `<class>`? What all links have you referred so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Div :**

The `<div>` tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.

```
<div>
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>
      London is the capital of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. 
    </p>
</div>
```

**Class :**

The HTML class attribute makes it possible to define equal styles for elements with the same class name.

```
<div class="cities">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` is a tag that defines a division or a section in an HTML document.
 The `<div>` tag is used to group block-elements to format them with CSS.

```
<div>
  <p>This is paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

**class** is defined in css, where we define what will be the styling of a tag with this class name. (stylingForDiv is name of class used in this exmaple).

```
.stylingForDiv{
                 background-color: black;
                 color: white;
                 margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
                 padding: 20px;     }
```

Inorder to apply styles of a css class (stylingForDiv in this example) to a div tag we need to associate css class with div tag which is done by using class attribute in div tag.

```
<div>
  <p>This is paragraph the same paragraph but styled using rules defined in stylingForDiv class .</p>
</div>
```

[image]

So, Div is a tag of HTML whereas class is attribute of HTML tag which is use to style HTML tag according to rule described in class defined in css.
unlike like `<div>` , class can not be written in angle bracket as it is not HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

The  tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.

The  element is often used as a container for other HTML elements to style them with CSS or to perform certain tasks with JavaScript.
Whilst the class is used to select any html elements and the  element can be given a class example

Answer (score 0):

is an HTML tag where as class is an attribute which can be assigned to any HTML tag including div tag.

For example :

```
<div class="firstDiv">First 1</div>
<div class="firstDiv">First 2</div>
<div class="secondDiv">Second</div>
```

If you are familiar id attribute, a HTML document can contain an ID only once where multiple tags can contain same class name.

[Here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200508/html_tags_vs_elements_vs_attributes/) is a simple explanation:

Also tag like `<class>` does not exist. So, this as per HTML standards is not valid : `<class>hello</class>`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.
When you create a div element you can use it only once, eg.

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

and you cannot use the div element two or more times, but there is a class element that you can use many times, eg.

```
<class id="container">
</class>

<div id="container2">
</div>

<class id="container">
</class>
```

To refer to div in css you have to use a hash:

```
#container
{
   ...
}
```

To refer to class in css you have to use a dot:

```
.container
{
   ...
}
```

I think that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

> The `***<div> element***` is very often used together with CSS, to layout a
>   web page.

while

> The HTML class ***attribute*** makes it possible to define equal styles for
>   elements with the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

1. `<div>` is a container tag whereas `class` is an attribute.
2. A `class` can be used in any tag, and any number of tags.
3. `class` is nothing but a name to css so that it can be used everywhere, without writing same styles everywhere. It works in the same way as a function in any programming language. It improves re-usability of code.
4. A container can have multiple space separetd classes, as `class = "cls1 cls2"`
5. Read more about [class](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp) and [div](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp).

For example:

`<div class= "mt5">
 <input type= "text" class="mt5" />
 </div>`

Where `mt5` is class (can be named anything) that represents `margin-top:5px` (to be defined initially).

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, a class selector is a name preceded by a full stop (“.”) and an ID selector is a name preceded by a hash character (“#”). The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.

Answer (score 0):

A  is a tag, and it's used to group elements that belong together, it's like a box, whereas,  class is an attribute, you use it like class="blah", it helps you style elements together, if you have more than one div and you want to style them the same way, they'll all be like:

Comment: This answer looks unfinished. "they'll all be like:" what?

Answer (score 0):

A **div** is a container tag that is used to define a division or a section in an HTML document, whereas a **class** is an attribute that specifies actions to be taken to one or more elements.

When using a class in CSS you have to specify the HTML elements you want it to affect by using a dot(.) and this can be done for multiple elements whereas while styling divs in CSS, you have to style each div separately.